# passing values in onClick handler for post-request in React

Tags: reactjs, frontend, http-post

This is a function sending post request consisting of 2 parameters: subject_id, document.

```
export const ask_expert = (subjectid, cdocumentdata) => {
      axios
        .post("/request/", {
          subject_id: subjectid ,
          document: documentdata,
    
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          alert(res.data.message);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("error" + err));
    };
```

I've imported this function to a **textEditor.js** file.
in this file I've  SUBMIT button where I've added an onClick functonality where I've to pass the above 2 parameters.

```
{/* SUBMIT BUTTON */}
         <Button
         type="submit"
         onClick={ () => ask_expert(subject,  value) }  
         // className="Choice_submitBtn"
       >
         Submit
       </Button>
```

now the 2 arguments in this ask_expert function in submit button is wrong. what values do I pass.
first is from **textEditor.js** file only where there is a submit button. I want to pass value from here

```
<Slate editor={editor} value={props.value} onChange={value => {
        props.setValue(value);}} >
        <div className="textEditor_toolbar">
          <div className="textEditor_buttonedit">
            <Navbar style={{padding: "0"}} expand="lg">
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Navbar.Brand>
                  <ButtonGroup>
                    <MarkButton format="bold" tooltip="bold" icon={faBold}/>
                    <MarkButton format="italic" icon={faItalic} />
                    <MarkButton format="underline" icon={faUnderline} />
                  </ButtonGroup>
                  <ButtonGroup>
                    <MarkButton2 format="code" icon={faCode}/>
                    <BlockButton format="bulleted-list" icon={faListUl} />
                    <BlockButton format="numbered-list" icon={faListOl} />
                  </ButtonGroup>
                </Navbar.Brand>     
                    <Nav>
                      <label className="custom-file-upload">
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          name="profileImg"
                          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                          multiple="false"
                          onChange={setImage}
                        />
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="custom-file-icon" icon={faPaperclip}/>
                      </label>
                    </Nav>
                    <Form> 
                      <Choice  value= {props.value} />
                    </Form>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
              </Navbar>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div>
        </div>
        <Editable
          className="textEditorMain"
          renderElement={renderElement}
          renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
          placeholder="Type your Question, Paste your Question text or Attach images or PDF here"
          spellCheck
          autoFocus
          useReadOnly
          onPaste = {onPaste}
          onKeyPress={event => {
            for (const hotkey in HOTKEYS) {
              if (isHotkey(hotkey, event )) {
                event.preventDefault()
                const mark = HOTKEYS[hotkey]
                toggleMark(editor, mark)
              }
            }
          }}
        />
      </Slate>
```

second thing i want to pass is from another **Choice.js** file. I want to pass value={suject} from here to submit button in **textEditor** file

```
<Form.Group className="Choice_formGrp">
            <Form.Label>Subject</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" value={subject} onChange={changeSubject}>
              {subjectList.map((sub, i) => {
                return <option value={sub}> {sub} </option>;
              })}
            </Form.Control>
```

Comment: does anybody know how to do?